# Microcontroller 89c52 - 7 segment multiplexing display

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I have an example program for uController written in C handling 7 segment multiplexing display.

I can access left or right part of display as following:

```
//declarations   
unsigned char xdata left    _at_ 0xFE00;
unsigned char xdata right   _at_ 0xFD00;

//use
left  = 0x06;
right = 0x5B;
```

And it will print "1" to left screen, "2" to right.

Now I'm wondering, how does that work?
Where did 0xFE00 adress came from and how it happens to display it to left screen (I know it's becouse there is '0' on P2_0 but I don't know how it is connnected to 'left' variable).

[image: 8 segment multipexing display]

Comment: The first thing you need to go is to check the register map on the MCU, to see which addresses that correspond to which port. You have to read the manual about how these register works. In addition to the data registers, are there also data direction registers etc? Now you go ahead and read the manual and _you_ tell _us_ what these registers do. I suppose you might have to do a burglary at a museum to get your hands on the manual for this MCU.

Comment: sfr P0      = 0x80;
sfr P2      = 0xA0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never programmed this beast but a look at your code, circuit diagram and the data sheet suggests that the LED pair is addressed as external memory: 8 data bits (otherwise port 0) are wired to the segment data pins and 2 address lines (otherwise port 2) are wired to the digit select pins.

The value `FE00` has bit 8 low and bit 9 high. So writing to address `FE00` causes `0` to be output from P2.0 (aka A8) and `1` to be output from P2.1 (aka A9), selecting the left LED, with the data presented on P0.

The value `FD00` has bit 8 high and bit 9 low. So writing to address `FD00` causes `1` to be output from P2.0 (aka A8) and `0` to be output from P2.1 (aka A9), selecting the right LED, and again the segment data is on P0.

The Special Function Registers will set up the required port mode.